# Download specific part of a canvas as image

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I am using react-konva to work with images on a canvas.
Now almost everything is working, except that I want to download part of the canvas as image.

I have look at the docs react-konva and it seems I can only download the whole canvas as image or use an external library to export to a pdf (which does allow me to set a specific location and size). But that is not an image.

I want to be able to give a specific location and size of the canvas to generate an image.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export part of the canvas. When you get reference to the `Konva.Stage` instance you can use `stage.toDataURL()` method for export. That method has arguments to control position and size:

```js
stageRef.current.toDataURL({ x: 10, y: 10, width: 1000, height: 1000 })
```

Comment: that works indeed. I got the download working, but the quality is kinda poor. I even tried to save a jpg, with the quality param set to 1, but that still has a poor quality. How can this be improved?

Comment: Wait I saw the pixelRatio, I can change that to 2 (will double its size), is there another way or is this the only way to increase quality?

Comment: @udarts it may depend on the use case, but it general it is a good approach to use `pixelRatio` for better quality.